# jupyter notebook: kernel is dead in python 3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

whenever i open jupyter notebook on my laptop and i try opening python 3 i get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\king\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\king\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-56c943cc-62b0-4c55-9067-51a84271800c.json'
```

please what do i do. 
none of the  inputs in the jupyter notebook is producing an output

Comment: what command are you using to start the notebook? have you tried `sudo`?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Jupyter Notebook? Also it seems you should try using `sudo` as Jay said because it said Permission denied.

Comment: i used jupyter notebook on the anaconda prompt to start it up and yeah i have tried uninstalling and installing it and still having the same issues. please what is `sudo`